# Python making an icon in the notification area

Tags: python, windows, gtk

I'm trying to make an icon in the notification area, using Python GTK. [For Reference, this is the area I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCjHl.png). I know how to make a simple notification from there, but I'm looking to have my program running in the background, and have a menu opened when the icon is clicked, similar to the dropbox icon. If anyone knows how, help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`gtk.StatusIcon`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkstatusicon.html), as [shown in this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130224082059/http://learngtk.org/pygtk-tutorial/statusicon.html). The documentation explicitly mentions Windows, so it should work there.

Answer (score 0):

```
app_icon = "Your path\youriconfile"
```

For example my icon file name is `bg` and extension `.ico` which is `bg.ico` so I have

```
app_icon = "Your path\bg.ico"
```